# How to read in an ArrayList to an arg constructer

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a classroom class that has a Classroom(String name, ArrayList students) as an arg constructer.But what happens when I read in the arraylist it reads in all the students from the different teachers e.g

```
TeacherA,john,mick

TeacherB,james,doe
```

Instead of only reading in john and mick for TeacherA it reads in all the students.
I dont know how to stop this.

```
ArrayList<Classroom> studentTeacher..... 
try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("txt.csv");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String fileLines;
    String[] parts; 
    ArrayList<String> students= new ArrayList<String>();

    while(br.ready()) {
        fileLines = br.readLine();
        parts = fileLines.split(",");
        int size = parts.length;
        for(int i =1; i<size; i++) {
            students.add(parts[i]);
        }
        studentTeacher.add(new Classroom(parts[0], students));
    }
    br.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Couldnt Read file");
}
return studentTeacher;
```

Comment: Where are you declaring your students object (ArrayList?).  If you aren't clearing it out each time you come into your while loop, you'll be adding more rows to it each time, and then adding that to your studentTeacher arraylist.  In other words, the first time through you add 10 students to it, for a total of 10.  Next time through you get 10 more, so now you have 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "reset" your List of Student(s) after you add it to your Map - you can't just clear() it because then your Map would still only have a single List reference.

```
studentTeacher.add(new Classroom(parts[0], students));
// Add this line.
students = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thats works perfectly thanks :) I would upvote your answer but I dont have enough rep

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution, it creates a new ArryList() for each line:

```
List<Classroom> studentTeacher..... 
    try{
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("txt.csv");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String fileLines;
        String[] parts; 
        List<String> students= null;

            while(br.ready()) {
                students= new ArrayList<String>(); // Creates a new ArrayList of Students for each new line.
                fileLines = br.readLine();
                parts = fileLines.split(",");
                int size = parts.length;
                for(int i =1; i<size; i++) {
                    students.add(parts[i]);
                }
                studentTeacher.add(new Classroom(parts[0], students));
            }
        br.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Couldnt Read file");
    }
return studentTeacher;
```

Good Luck!